How do I print to console with printf()? (using GCC in Windows 10)
I am new to assembly code, and would like to try it as a means to add extra functionality C++ and C. I'm still on the Hello World phase of asm use, however, and have been having trouble with the following code. It assembles, runs, causes a console to pop up, but does not print anything to the console, nor to the PowerShell window I use to punch in the command line.
.extern printf
.extern scanf
.global main

.text

main:

    mov %rsp, %rbp
    sub $0x30, %rsp

    movabsq $formatStr, %rcx
    mov $0x6, %edi
    mov $0x0, %al
    call    printf

    xor %rax, %rax
    add $0x30, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret

.data

formatStr: 
    .asciz "The int is %d\n"

.end

This was built using the following command line in PowerShell:
gcc "D:\Code\foo.s" -o "D:\Code\foo.exe"
And executed using the following PowerShell line:
Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Code\foo.exe"
It's GCC version 13.1.0.
I have included the obligatory newline at the end of the .s file.
Any suggestions on what could be causing the lack of output?

You put the 6 into the wrong register, it should go to edx. al does not need to be zeroed, that's the linux convention. You are missing the push rbp so you will get a crash.

Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?
